# Laptop is on then screen goes black a few seconds later

Tags: display, laptop

I am not really sure whether this is the right place to post my question but it was the most relevant category.

I opened (deassembled) my laptop for periodic cleaning but after reassembling it, when I power it on the it works fine for 3 seconds then the screen goes off.

When I attach my laptop to an external screen it works fine without any troubles. The only issue so far is that the screen blacks out.

I googled the issue but couldn't find an answer.

My laptop is Dell inspiron n5110 i7

Comment: Definitely off-topic here, but I flagged your question to be moved to superuser

Comment: @FrederikNielsen Thanks and apologies for inconvenience 

Comment: Is it possible it is expected to be outputting the monitor to a 2nd screen that is unplugged?

Comment: @vn. Couldn't get what you mean. Can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been solved.

I disassembled the laptop again and made sure everything is in place this time and it worked.

Probably a cable or a pin that was not fitted accurately caused this problem.

Thank you for your help